# HazelcastRepository - how to save a new entity (with the id from sequence) and put it to the map

Tags: spring-boot, hazelcast

I would like to save a new entity using HazlecastRepository.
When the id is null, the KeyValueTemplate use SecureRandom and generate id which is like -123123123123123123.

I don't want to save id like that, instead of that i woud like to get it from sequence in db and put it to the map.

I have found 2 solutions:

1) In AdminService get the next value from sequence in database and set it

2) Create atomic counter id in the Hazelcast server and init it with the current value from the sequence. In AdminService get counter, increment value and set id.

but they are not very pretty.

Do you have any other ideas?

The code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableHazelcastRepositories(basePackages = "com.test")
public class HazelcastConfig {

    @Bean
    public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance(ClientConfig clientConfig) {
        return HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("client")
    public ClientConfig clientConfig() {
        ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
        clientConfig.setClassLoader(HazelcastConfig.class.getClassLoader());
        ClientNetworkConfig networkConfig = clientConfig.getNetworkConfig();
        networkConfig.addAddress("127.0.0.1:5701");
        networkConfig.setConnectionAttemptLimit(20);

        return clientConfig;
    }

    @Bean
    public KeyValueTemplate keyValueTemplate(ClientConfig clientConfig) {
        return new KeyValueTemplate(new HazelcastKeyValueAdapter(hazelcastInstance(clientConfig)));
    }

}


@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AdminService {

private final UserRepository userRepository;

    ...

    @Transactional
    public User addOrUpdateUser(UserUpdateDto dto) {
        validate(dto);
        User user = dto.getId() != null ? userService.getUser(dto.getId()) : new User();
        mapUser(user, dto);
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    ...

}

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends HazelcastRepository<User, Long> {

}

@KeySpace("users")
@Entity
@Table(name = "users)
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User extends DateAudit implements Serializable {

    @javax.persistence.Id
    @org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
    // @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "user_generator")
    // @SequenceGenerator(name="user_generator", sequenceName = "user_seq")
    private Long id;

    ...
}
```

Hazelcast server:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class UserLoader implements ApplicationContextAware, MapStore<Long, User> {

    private static UserJpaRepository userJpaRepository;

    @Override
    public User load(Long key) {
        log.info("load({})", key);
        return userJpaRepository.findById(key).orElse(null);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<Long, User> loadAll(Collection<Long> keys) {
        Map<Long, User> result = new HashMap<>();
        for (Long key : keys) {
            User User = this.load(key);
            if (User != null) {
                result.put(key, User);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<Long> loadAllKeys() {
        return userJpaRepository.findAllId();
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        userJpaRepository = applicationContext.getBean(UserJpaRepository.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void store(Long aLong, User user) {
        userJpaRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void storeAll(Map<Long, User> map) {
        for (Map.Entry<Long, User> mapEntry : map.entrySet()) {
            store(mapEntry.getKey(), mapEntry.getValue());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Long aLong) {
        userJpaRepository.deleteById(aLong);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteAll(Collection<Long> collection) {
        collection.forEach(this::delete);
    }
}

public interface UserJpaRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT u.id FROM User u")
    Iterable<Long> findAllId();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is no better way than what you described.

I'd go with the second solution, because then you're at least coupled to Hazelcast server only.